# Can I combine a possessive pronoun and the genitive of a noun?

Tags: grammar-choice, pronouns, genitive

Today in chat we spoke briefly about an earlier discussion I had had with [Cerberus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/30/cerberus) in Latin.
(In case you did not know, we have a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) for this site.)
I realized that I do not know how to put both *ego* and *Cerberus* in a possessive form together to refer to our discussion.
Would *colloquium meum et Cerberi* be valid?
These "mixed possessives" look weird.
Of course I could say *colloquium inter me et Cerberum*, but what I want to know is whether one can combine possessive pronouns with genitives like this.

Comment: FWIW, Church Latin uses _ac_ to conjunctively join possessives: _[orate frates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orate_fratres) ut meum ac vestrum sacrificium acceptabile fiat apud Deum Patrem omnipotentem_.

Comment: Nearby in the order of the Mass there is also a decliend construction _quoque_ poss + poss _-que_, that sounds to me like English _as well as_: _ad utilitatem quoque nostram totiusque Ecclesiae suae sanctae_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eugene McCartney has an article in *Classical Philology* (XIV 3 July 1919) entitled ["Greek and Latin Constructions in Implied Agreement"](https://books.google.com/books?id=s43PAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186) that mentions these constructions in its opening notes.

While talking about the "closeness of the relationship between the genitive of possession and the possessive adjective," he cites the coordination of the two in the same sentence as supporting evidence. He gives numerous examples that correspond to the OP's example sentence:

Cic. *Fam.* xii.4.2:

> summa laus et tua et Bruti est

Caes. *B.G.* iii.20:

> calamitatem aut propriam suam aut temporum

Verg. *Ecl.* iii.1:

> Dic mihi, Damoeta, cuium pecus? an Meliboei?

Ovid *Met.* iv.680:

> nomen terraeque suumque

Ovid *Trist*. i.3.97:

> nataeque meumque corpus

He also cites some interesting (non-possessive) examples where adjectives are coordinated with the genitive, to further demonstrate that Latin allows this:

Livy xxi.29.4:

> haud sane incruentam ancipitisque certaminis victoriam.